# when a solr document is updated, the indexing date is changed?

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, relevance

In Solr the default ordering is ASC if two documents have the same relevancy taking in consideration the index dateTime. But lets say if one of the records is updated, the index dateTime is changed? - taking in consideration that solr when it does an update in fact delete that record and inserts it again. So when a document is updated the original indexing date is kept and an update column is modified, or the indexing dateTime is modified causing at equal relevancy a new order of the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default order is the order the documents are stored in the index (not some dateTime column). This is usually the order in which the documents are added to the index.

If you delete and add a document, that will usually result in the new document being at the end, if the relevance score is the same.

So, yes, If you upload a new document, that may change the ordering.

Comment: Thank you, for the answer. This is what i wanted to know for sure. I was 99% sure but i wanted to be 100%. That index column it happens to be a date column.